# Node.js Express - Specifying path to root of app

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to access a folder in my app that contains a few .js controller modules.

in the head of one of my .html files I have this script declared:

the problem is when the app is running, the application seems to know what the current path is, so the path to my script is not relative to the actual file system, it is relative to the current path of the app, which I might say is very strange.

So, the quick fix would be to easily specify the root of my application, since fancy_scripts is just one folder down from the root.

the following doesn't work, because of the problem I mentioned above

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fancy_scripts/userHomeController.js"></script>
</head>
```

but there has to be a way to specify the global root of the app with something like a double slash "//"

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//fancy_scripts/userHomeController.js"></script>
</head>
```

(the above doesn't work either, // is the root in MS Windows (I think), but not an Express app) this is a straightforward problem, with I hope a straightforward solution. There might be a better way to do things however.

I have these 3 lines of code already:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/fancy_scripts')); 
app.use('/fancy_scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/fancy_scripts'));
```

Answer (score 2):

When using express, the path will be routed through one of your declared handlers or via the static module if you've set that up. Normally Express is configured to use static and to map it to your applications public folder. When using the express-generator that folder is located at `<approot>/public/`. So in order to access something like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancy_scripts/userHomeController.js"></script>
</head>
```

You'll need to put userHomeController in `<approot>/public/fancy_scripts/userHomeController.js`

Comment: Thanks Timothy - I added some info to the bottom of the question. I had some code dealing with this already.

Comment: Where does this fancy_scripts directory exist? It should be serving files relative to your application entry point, not your OS root directory. You should also not define multiple static paths like that. Just define one. Keep in mind, the folder name that you specify in the static function is NOT included in the path on the client.

Comment: ok thanks, I was using Windows as an example where you can define the root with "//".

Comment: you can't via node. Node is processing those client requests, not windows.